# Parse variables from string and add them to an array with Bash

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, sed

In Bash, how can I get the strings between acolades (without the '_value' suffix) from for example

```
"\\*\\* ${host_name_value}.${host_domain_value} - ${host_ip_value}\\*\\*"
```

and put them into an array?

The result for the above example should be something like:

```
var_array=("host_name" "host_domain")
```

The string could also contain other stuff such as:

```
"${package_updates_count_value} ${package_updates_type_value} updates"
```

The result for the above example should be something like:

```
var_array=("package_updates_count" "package_updates_type")
```

All variables end with `_value`. There could 1 or more variables in the string.

Not sure what would be the most efficient way and how I'd best handle this. Regex? Sed?

Comment: TL;DR: you want the name of every variable (the contents of `${}` except that you want `_value` removed from the variable name? Do all variables end in `_value`?

Comment: correct, all vars end with _value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
input='\\*\\* ${host_name_value}.${host_domain_value} \\*\\*'
# would also work with cat input or the like.
myarray=($(echo "$input" | awk -F'$' \
  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {match($i, /{([^}]*)_value}/, a); print a[1]}}'))
```

Split your line(s) on `$`. Check if a column contains `{ }`. If it does, print what's after `{` and before `_value}`. (If not, it will print out the empty string, which bash array creation will ignore.)

Comment: this is the most flexible solution, and I'll be using it, tx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If there are only two variables, this will work.

```
input='\\*\\* ${host_name_value}.${host_domain_value} \\*\\*'

first=$(echo $input | sed -r -e 's/[}].+//' -e 's/.+[{]//')
last=$(echo $input | sed -r -e 's/.+[{]//' -e 's/[}].+//')

output="var_array=(\"$first\" \"$last\")"
```

Maybe not very efficient and beautiful, but it works well.

Comment: thanks, but yes, there could indeed be one or more variables. I clarified in the q

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a string variable:

```
$ str='\\*\\* ${host_name_value}.${host_domain_value} - ${host_ip_value}\\*\\*'
```

Use `grep -o` to print all matching words.

```
$ grep -o '\${\w*_value}' <<< "$str"
${host_name_value}
${host_domain_value}
${host_ip_value}
```

Then remove `${` and `_value}`.

```
$ grep -o '\${\w*_value}' <<< "$str" | sed 's/^\${//; s/_value}$//'
host_name
host_domain
host_ip
```

Finally, use `readarray` to safely read the results into an array.

```
$ readarray -t var_array < <(grep -o '\${\w*_value}' <<< "$str" | sed 's/^\${//; s/_value}$//')
$ declare -p var_array
declare -a var_array=([0]="host_name" [1]="host_domain" [2]="host_ip")
```